# Store output of a select to a variable array in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table called `Structure1` in that I want to store `Structure_name` values into an array and compare with another table `Structure2` with column `item` and display the values if matching.

```
    DECLARE  @Structure1  TABLE
    (
        Structure_name VARCHAR[128]
    )

    SELECT Structure_name FROM Structure1

    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO xyz FROM Structure1 
    
    FOR i=1..xyz
        SELECT Structure_name FROM Structure2 WHERE ITEM = Structure[i]
        PRINT Structure_name values..
    END FOR
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems that you come from another programming language background. In most (if not all) relational databases, your operations are done in a set basis, not one by one. They are optimized to work that way also.

You can simply join both tables and display all the matching values.

```
SELECT
    S2.Structure_name
FROM
    Structure2 AS S2
    INNER JOIN Structure1 AS S1 ON S2.Structure_name = S1.Structure_name
```

---

**EDIT:** If you really want to use looping, you can use a `CURSOR`. Basic syntax is like the following:

```
DECLARE StructureCursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT
        S.Structure_name
    FROM
        Structure2 AS S

OPEN StructureCursor

DECLARE @StructureName VARCHAR(200)

FETCH NEXT FROM StructureCursor INTO @StructureName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    DECLARE @MatchingStructureName VARCHAR(200)

    SELECT
        @MatchingStructureName = S1.Structure_name
    FROM
        Structure1 AS S1
    WHERE
        S1.Structure_name = @StructureName

    PRINT (@MatchingStructureName)

    FETCH NEXT FROM StructureCursor INTO @StructureName

END

CLOSE StructureCursor
DEALLOCATE StructureCursor
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what JOINs do in RDBMS

This gives all matching rows between the 2 tables

```
SELECT
   *
FROM
  @Structure1 s1
  JOIN
  Structure2 s2 ON s1.Structure_name  = s2.ITEM
```

Comment: i want to use array concept and do ..but in mssql there is no array concept, so am using temporary tables and want to do...

Comment: have to do many validations ..so need to use this array concept. thanks.

Comment: @learner: There are very few cases where you need to loop in SQL or "use arrays". We also answered what you asked. If you want help on your real problem, then give us the real problem.